# брандмауэр windows

Tags: windows, firewall

значится есть тип сети - Общедоступная.

**ПК1. Windows 7:**
есть проброс на роутере, условный 65000 на 3389
правило на win7 - разрешить входящие TCP для <БелыйIP> на 3389

как это работает - никому недоступен порт 3389 кроме <БелыйIP>

**ПК2. Windows 11**:
есть проброс на роутере, условный 65000 на 3389
правило на win11 - разрешить входящие TCP для <БелыйIP> на 3389

как это работает - **ВСЕМ** доступен порт 3389, Windows11 воспринимает все белые src как 192.168.*.* от роутера.

Что я делаю не так?